# Im trying to make a fireball charge ability but it doesnt work and says argument 1 missing or nil how can i fix this? error at line 4 (not full code)

Tags: roblox

```
if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and not Debounce then
    Debounce = true
    Charging = true
    Server:InvokeServer("Fireball", "Charge", {})
    local Charge = 0
```

(Im still new to this kind of code)